# Finding a path through a connected component where every vertex is visited exactly once

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

I have a large graph of connected vertices (a connected component) and I am looking for a path that goes through all of them, but never goes through one vertex twice. This isn't always possible. For instance, in the following example [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)), it is obvious that there is no path that visits every vertex where no vertex is visited more than once:

[image: wikipedia connected component]

But if it was tweaked slightly, so that it has more edges (connections), then there are some paths that can go through every vertex exactly once. I've tweaked it and numbered the vertices to give one such path:

[image: tweaked connected component]

My graph is like this one, where I know that there is a possible path. However, it is quite large (20,000 vertices, each with anywhere between 2 and 11 edges). I implemented depth-first search and breadth-first search but the graph is simply too big to find a path through (it will take too long to compute).

---

So my question is: Is there another algorithm that can solve this problem, specifically more efficiently than depth-first or breadth-first search?

It is a little bit like the traveling salesman problem except that cities are only reachable from specific other cities, and distance between those is equal.

Comment: Does your graph have a [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory))? ​ Is your graph [planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)? ​ In any case, try [approximating your graph's treewidth](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.29.7198&rep=rep1&type=pdf), since low treewidth allows efficient algorithms for your problem. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're describing is called the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) (a Hamiltonian path is one that goes through every node once and exactly once). This problem is, unfortunately, known to be **NP**-hard, so there are no known polynomial-time algorithms for solving this problem. As a result, you are unlikely to find a solution that works efficiently using a simple breadth-first search or depth-first search.

There is a somewhat famous dynamic programming algorithm for solving this problem. If you search online for "Hamiltonian path DP," you should find some good links on the subject.